# Energy Proportional to the Square of the Amplitude

Tags: waves

I don't understand how the energy of a wave is proportional to its amplitude squared...For example, if we consider simple harmonic motion at the maximum displacement, there is no kinetic energy and there is just potential energy. How does that lead to the energy being proportional to the amplitude squared?

Comment: Use conservation of energy. When the kinetic energy is $0$, and thus $x=A$ (A is the amplitude of oscillation), $E=U(A)$. This potential energy $U$ at this point is $\frac{1}{2}kA^2$, which is equal to the energy due to conservation of energy.

Comment: The definition of the energy comes as the answer below tells you. But, if it wasn't on square but on one, what would you think then it will happen? If the body is in -A instead of A, you would have a negative energy with 0 potential at the r=0?

Comment: Sorry. With A I mean the amplitude position

Answer (score 1):

One answer is:  it's the expression that is found to be conserved and can be identified as energy.

Another answer: consider a harmonic oscillator. It obeys Hooke's Law $F=-kx$.  Find the potential energy at max extension by calculating the work needed to get there starting at the equilibrium position $$\Delta U = -W = -\int_0^{X_{max}} F\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{X_{max}} kx\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\,k\,{X_{max}}^2$$